# Azure Dev Ops, Unable to deploy an API Management using bicep. Keep getting the error 'CustomHostnameOwnershipFailed'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

As said in the question above. The errror message is written below:

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidParameters","message":"Invalid parameter: CustomHostnameOwnershipCheckFailed. A CNAME record pointing from test to apiaresocool.azure-api.net was not found.."}]}
```

I've tried deploying the app manually and it works fine. It creates the cname for me, without needing to verify it exists.

Here is my bicep file. I'm using main to call on this bicep file:

```
 param api_Management_Name string = 'apiManage'

resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-08-01' = {
name: api_Management_Name
location: resourceGroup().location

sku: {
capacity:0
name: 'Consumption'

}
properties: {
  customProperties: {

  }
  notificationSenderEmail: null
  publisherEmail: '******' //I add my email here
  publisherName: 'Clarion Housing'
  virtualNetworkType: 'None'
  hostnameConfigurations: [
    {
     
      certificatePassword: null
      defaultSslBinding: true
      encodedCertificate: null
      hostName: 'test'
      identityClientId: null
      keyVaultId: null
      negotiateClientCertificate: false
      type: 'Proxy'
    }
  ]
}

 }
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your bicep file with us ?

Comment: My bad. I've added the bicep file.

Comment: I imagine the `hostName: 'test'` property is the one that is causing issue. you can remove the `hostnameConfigurations` from your bicep file and it should work.